# Firebase database conflicting getters for name: getAddress

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently trying out Google's Places API and meanwhile trying to push a `Place` to my Firebase database. The code below tries to do that but errors out when it is called.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
            String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
            Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            String userUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
            DatabaseReference userRef = database.getReference("users/" + userUid);

            userRef.setValue(place);
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
11-23 18:34:24.874 13155-13155/io.app.roomie E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: io.app.roomie, PID: 13155
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {io.app.roomie/io.app.roomie.MainActivity}: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found conflicting getters for name: getAddress
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4089)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4132)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1533)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found conflicting getters for name: getAddress
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy$zza.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy.zzj(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy.zzca(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamy.zzbz(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(Unknown Source)
    at io.app.roomie.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:81)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6932)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4085)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4132) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1533) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Sorry about the code formatting. I couldn't get it to work otherwise.

Comment: Is this Place class coming from the Places API?

Comment: Yes, it's from `com.google.android.gms.location.places`.

Comment: That kind of explains it. That class is not meant to be directly sent to Firebase, you should make your own POJO class, copy the data, and save that.

Comment: Oh right, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @vzsg want to post that as answer? Otherwise one of us will have to find a duplicate. :-/

Comment: I just did, thanks for the nudge. (I'll go and hit up Meta about this situation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place` is not meant to be directly saved into Firebase.

You should write a simple POJO class that contains only the fields you need from Place, copy the data, and save this simple object into the database.